# How to run a .bat file when running project

Tags: visual-studio, batch-file, adb

I want to automatically run a batch file which connects my Android's Phone Wireless ADB when I run a solution. How can i get Visual studios 2013 to Run a Bat file when I hit F5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure you can run a bat file only when the project is run, but you can run a bat file on the build action.

Go to project properties (Alt+Enter), then the "Build Events" tab. In post build event command line add something like the following:

```
"$(SolutionDir)<path to bat file>\batfile.bat" "$(SolutionDir)\"
```